# bash check all file in a directory for their extension

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am writing a shell script to read all the files in the give directory by the user input then count how many files with that extension. I just started learning Bash and I am not sure why it this not locating the files or reading the directory. I am only putting 2 example but my count is always 0.

This is how I run my script

```
$./check_ext.sh /home/user/temp
```

my script check_ext.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

count1=0
count2=0

for file in "ls $1"
do
if [[ $file == *.sh ]]; then 
    echo "is a txt file"
    (( count1++ ))
elif [[ $file == *.mp3 ]]; then
    echo "is a mp3 file"
    (( count2++ ))
fi  
done;

echo $count $count2
```

Comment: If you are just trying to solve a problem `find` can do this for you. If you are trying to learn bash programming, press on good sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"ls $1"` doesn't execute `ls` on `$1`, it just a plain string. Command substitution syntax is `$(ls "$1")`

However there is no need to use `ls`, just use globbing:

```
count1=0
count2=0

for file in "$1"/*; do
   if [[ $file == *.sh ]]; then 
       echo "is a txt file"
       (( count1++ ))
   elif [[ $file == *.mp3 ]]; then
       echo "is a mp3 file"
       (( count2++ ))
   fi  
done

echo "counts: $count1 $count2"
```

`for file in "$1"/*` will iterate through all the files/directories in the directory denoted by `$1`

---

**EDIT:** For doing it recursively inside a directory:

```
count1=0
count2=0

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   if [[ $file == *.sh ]]; then 
       echo "is a txt file"
       (( count1++ ))
   elif [[ $file == *.mp3 ]]; then
       echo "is a mp3 file"
       (( count2++ ))
   fi  
done < <(find "$1" -type f -print0)

echo "counts: $count1 $count2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to read its sub folder? like if there are files inside "/home/user/temp/sub/sub"

Comment: Just run the loop like: `for file in "$1"/* "$1"sub/*; do` but if you want all the sub-folders then I suggest using `find`

Comment: Sorry I change the code 'FILES=$(find $1) for file in $FILES)' but is not looping the for loop. Is reading the directory as a whole chunk of text not individual file

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
count1=0
count2=0

for f in "$1"/*; do
  case $f in
     (*.sh) printf '%s is a txt file\n' "$f"; : "$((count1+=1))" ;;
    (*.mp3) printf '%s is a mp3 file\n' "$f"; : "$((count2+=1))" ;;
  esac
done

printf 'counts: %d %d\n' "$count1" "$count2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash arrays for this too: if you only want to deal with extensions `sh` and `mp3`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

shs=( "$1"/*.sh )
mp3s=( "$1"/*.mp3 )

printf 'counts: %d %d\n' "${#shs[@]}" "${#mp3s[@]}"
```

If you want to deal with more extensions, you can generalize this process:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

exts=( .sh .mp3 .gz .txt )
counts=()

for ext in "${exts[@]}"; do
    files=( "$1"/*."$ext" )
    counts+=( "${#files[@]}" )
done

printf 'counts:'
printf ' %d' "${counts[@]}"
echo
```

If you want to deal with all extensions (using associative arrays, available in Bash ≥4)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

declare -A exts

for file in "$1"/*.*; do
    ext=${file##*.}
    ((++'exts[$ext]'))
done

for ext in "${!exts[@]}"; do
    printf '%s: %d\n' "$ext" "${exts[$ext]}"
done
```